# Count of id per day using window function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to count `track_uri` that are associated to a given `playlist_uri` in a day in a one month window and have composed the following sql:

```
SELECT
  playlist_uri, playlist_date, track_uri, count(track_uri) 
  over (partition by playlist_uri, playlist_date) as count_tracks
FROM
  tbl1
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN '2017-09-09' AND '2017-10-09'
  AND playlist_uri in (
    SELECT playlist_uri from tbl2 WHERE playlist_owner  = "spotify"
  )
```

However I am getting the following output:

[image]

I instead would like it to show me the count of `track_uri` for each `playlist_uri` on each day.

Would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Can you confirm that there are not in fact 50 track_uri records for that playlist on that date? You did not specify an order by clause, so the data is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: yes I can confirm I ran with order by before and saw the same result. I have got the output I need now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you might not need to use the window function for that:

```
SELECT
  playlist_uri, playlist_date, COUNT(DISTINCT track_uri)
FROM
  tbl1
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN '2017-09-09' AND '2017-10-09'
  AND playlist_uri in (
    SELECT playlist_uri from tbl2 WHERE playlist_owner  = "spotify"
  )
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Thanks it does the job, I think I was over complicating it as this is only part of a much larger query